# getting char element like array in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, char

I've implemented a dynamic array with initial size and insert an array of two columns in it something like `{{"aa","bb"},{"cc","dd"},{"ff","gg"}}` here is my code.the element looks to store coorectly in array but i dont know how to get the elements like `ptr_arr[i][j]`.

```
typedef struct {
    char **array;
    size_t used;
    size_t size;
} Array;

void initArray(Array *a, size_t initialSize) {
    a->array = (char **)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(char *));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        a->array[i] = (char *) malloc(initialSize * sizeof(char *));
    }
    a->used = 0;
    a->size = initialSize;
}

void insertArray(Array *a, char* (*element)[2]) {
    if (a->used == a->size) {
        a->size *= 2;
        a->array = (char **)realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(char));
    }
    a->array[a->used++] = *(*element);

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Array ptr_arr;
    initArray(&ptr_arr, 1);
    char *b[] = {"85","9u"};
    insertArray(&ptr_arr, &b);
    printf("%s \n", (ptr_arr.array[0][1])); //this is just i want to use
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a->array = (char **)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(char *));` --> `a->array = malloc(sizeof *(a->array) * 2);`

Comment: @chux what's the problem?i didn't get it.

Comment: Your code `malloc(initialSize * sizeof(char *))` allocates 1 pointer.  `malloc(sizeof *(a->array) * 2);` allocates 2 pointers for use in the following `for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {`

Comment: @chux nothing changed still i cant use it in that way.

Comment: "cant use it in that way" lacks details.  Please expand.

Comment: A pointer is not an array.

Comment: Do not cast the return of `malloc` and do not `realloc` the pointer itself (if `realloc` fails, you lose the reference to the original block of memory). Instead, `void *tmp = realloc(a->array, a->size *2 * sizeof(char)); if (!tmp) {..handle error..; return;}; a->array = tmp; a->size *= 2;`

Comment: @mike fayya  What are you exactly going to output with the printf call?

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char* (*array)[2];
    size_t used;
    size_t size;
} Array;

void initArray(Array *a, size_t initialSize) {
    a->array = malloc(initialSize * sizeof(char *[2]));
    a->used = 0;
    a->size = initialSize;
}

void insertArray(Array *a, char* (*element)[2]) {
    if (a->used == a->size) {
        a->size *= 2;
        a->array = realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(char *[2]));
    }
    a->array[a->used][0] = element[0][0];
    a->array[a->used++][1] = element[0][1];
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Array ptr_arr;
    initArray(&ptr_arr, 1);
    char *b[] = {"85","9u"};
    insertArray(&ptr_arr, &b);
    printf("%s \n", (ptr_arr.array[0][1]));//9u
    free(ptr_arr.array);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A 2-dimensional array is an **Array of pointers to other arrays**. To do it dynamically you have to allocate a single dimensional array for each line and 1 single dimensional array to hold the pointers for those arrays (lines).
Something like:

```
char **Array;
char *Array_line;

Array = malloc(initialSizeY * sizeof(char *));

for(int i=0; i<initialSizeY; i++)
{
    Array_line = malloc(initialSizeX * sizeof(char));
    Array[i] = Array_line;
}
```

Then you could acces your data using **Array[i][j]** where **i** points to the i-th line of the array and **j** is the j-th char of that line.

To free this array, you should first crawl it, free each line of it (Array[i])  and then free the pointer holder array (Array).

Comment: Detail: `int a[3][4]` is an example of a 2D array.  With `char **Array;`, `Array` is not a 2D array, but a pointer to a `char *`.

Comment: @mike fayya - What exactly do you need? -  A two dimensional array of chars, a single-dimensional array of strings or a two-dimensinal array of strings? In your main() `printf("%s \n", (ptr_arr.array[0][1]));` would try to access a 2D string array which is a 3D array of chars!

Comment: @TodorSimeonov i just want two dimensional array of chars like {{"aa","bb"}}.

Comment: @mike-fayya  `{{"aa","bb"}}` is not a two dimensional array of chars. That's a two dimensional array of string (or three dimensional array of chars, since a string is just an arrays of chars).